# How to store a list in firebase firestore?

Tags: node.js, list, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store a list with firebase firestore, but I always get a encoding error:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot encode value: a,b,c

I have tried the following code snippets for **node js**:

```
const data = {
  a: "hello world",
  b: ["a", "b", "c"]
};

const res = await db.collection('data').doc('one').set(data);
```

and

```
const data = {
  a: "hello world",
  b: new Array(["a", "b", "c"])
};

const res = await db.collection('data').doc('one').set(data);
```

and

```
const data = {
  a: "hello world",
  b: []
};

const res = await db.collection('data').doc('one').set(data);
```

of which these all result in the same encoding error.

I have also tried to store a list as the following the blog post here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

```
{
  0: "a",
  1: "b",
  2: "c"
}
```

but this stored it as a object not a list and I need to store it as a list.

I can create new documents with lists in the firebase console, but i cant do it programmatically. I am using node js.

Thank you for aany help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a solution after looking at the firebase docs a bit more.

This page : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data told me that I could use array union to do this. Here is the working code sample:

```
const data = {
  a: "hello world",
  b: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("a")
};

const res = await db.collection('data').doc('one').set(data);
```